# Android SQLite CursorIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For some reason when the username I input is not found, the application crashes. But when the username is found it seems to run perfect. I even do a check to see if the returned cursor == null. Heres the code

```
    public boolean isUserAuthenticated(String username, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean authenticated = false;
    String[] columns = new String[] {LOGIN_USERNAME, LOGIN_PASSWORD};
    String sqlUsername = "\"" + username + "\"";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(LOGIN_TABLE, columns, LOGIN_USERNAME + "="+ sqlUsername, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String passwordAttachedToUsername = c.getString(1);
        if(passwordAttachedToUsername.equals(password)) {
            authenticated = true;
        }
    }

    return authenticated;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Cursor object may not be null, but the size of its result set is 0. Instead of:

```
if (c != null) {
    ...
}
```

try:

```
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Also, as @mu is too short mentioned, you could just use the return value of c.moveToFirst() in your conditional:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    String passwordAttachedToUsername = c.getString(1);
    if (passwordAttachedToUsername.equals(password)) {
        authenticated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could check the `moveToFirst` return value: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29

Comment: True. That is cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, the condition should be:

```
if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
```

Second, you can refactor

```
String passwordAttachedToUsername = c.getString(1);
if(passwordAttachedToUsername.equals(password)) {
    authenticated = true;
    }
```

with this instead:

```
authenticated = password.equals(c.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    ...
}
```

to

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    ...
}
```

which will return true if `c != null` and the size of the cursor is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` command will always return a cursor so your test for null will always fail.  You need to check the count the cursor contains using `cursor.getCount()`

Comment: Don't you mean: your test for null will always pass?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String passwordAttachedToUsername = c.getString(1);
          if(passwordAttachedToUsername.equals(password)) {
           authenticated = true;
    }}
                    // your logic goes here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Record Found", 1000).show();
                }
```